# Save complete model in session - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-session

I want to save complete model in session, so I can use data easily in entire application.

After successful login in application I am saving model in session and session save in database in `ci_session` table.

**Code I tried:**

```
$loginSuccess = $this->login_model->doLogin($username, $password);
if($loginSuccess) {
    $this->login_model->initialize();   // this will set value in private variable
    $serializelogin = serialize($this->login_model);
    $this->session->set_userdata('userprofile', $serializelogin);
}
```

**This code gives me an error:**

```
Error Number: 2006

MySQL server has gone away
```

**Update:** I change `user_data` column of table `ci_session` from text to longtext

Comment: sessions aren't really meant for this. i think you are optimizing or attempting to before determining if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0):

U need to start by creating a session.

```
//Destroy old session
$this->session->sess_destroy();

//Create a fresh, brand new session
 $this->session->sess_create();

 //Set session data
$this->session->set_userdata($row);
```

Basically $row is an array.
$row = $serializelogin->row_array();

or

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('active_flag' => false, 'active_status' => 0));
```

make sure the data which has been returned from the model is in row_array format.

Comment: Hope this would help you.!